# How to specify Prestashop's contact form from e-mail?

Tags: php, prestashop, cpanel

My hosting provider has an anti-spam rule, that hosted websites can send emails only from addresses registered with the hosting plan.

**How can I specify, in a Prestashop website's contact form, the sender e-mail address to be a specific email address (an e-mail belonging to the hosting plan) instead of the visitor's email address?**

I cannot find such setting, and google does not show me any related topic.

Comment: http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/E-Mail+Parameters

Comment: I don't see here any such setting

Comment: @SinistraD How are u sending the e-mail? plain `php` mail function or lib like swiftmailer?

Comment: Here http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/E-Mail+Parameters the second option (set my own SMTP parameters). The test e-mail works properly.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately for you Prestashop does not a have a specific setting to change what email address is being used to send the contact form.

Either you change the general prestashop email setting to use the php mail function (which *should* not cause problems with you Provider spam settings) or you will have to override the ContactController ( see http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors ).

In the ContactController override then paste the whole `postProcess()` function and add

```
$from = Configuration::get('PS_SHOP_EMAIL');
```

above the block starting with  `if (empty($contact->email)) {` (line 186 in the original controller file). This will change the sender to whatever email address you set as the default for the shop.